# Push-forward of divisors and intersections

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry, intersection-theory, divisors, pushforward

Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be a surjective finite morphism of varieties, with $X$ normal and $Y$ smooth. Let $D\subset X$ be a divisor and $C\subset Y$ a curve. Does the equality
$$C\cdot f_{*}D = f^{*}C\cdot D$$
always hold under these hypothesis?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Is $D$ a Cartier divisor?

Comment: Yes, $D$ is a Cartier divisor on $X$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $W = C \times_Y X$. I imagine $f^*C$ is suitably interpreted as the chow class on $W$ given by $C \cdot X$. Write $i : C \subseteq Y$, $f': W \to C$, $i' : W \to X$. (Suppose $i$ is l.c.i. so $i^!$ makes sense, or use obstruction theories. This is automatic if $C, Y$ are smooth). Then Gysin pullback and pushforward commute, so $i^! f_* [D] = f'_* i'^![D] \in A_*(C)$. This is one interpretation of your formula, but beware that $i'^!$ and $i^!$ may differ by the "excess intersection formula" if $f$ isn't flat.

If you're just interested in verifying that the intersection numbers agree, those are given by pushing forward to a point.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Just a question. Where did you use that $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is finite in your argument?

Comment: I suppose the same argument works for f proper, but be careful because in that case the pushforward could just send D to zero.